# Sending a Group Email using MS Access

Tags: email, ms-access

Why isn't this working!?! Apparently my database can't find the field "" referred to in your expression.? signed, rather frustrated - ps.

```
Private Sub Command17_Click()
On Error GoTo Err_Command17_Click

Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Dim strEmailAddress

Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset([CourseRosterMaterialsEmail_Query])

Do Until rst.EOF
  strEmailAddress = strEmailAddress & rst([CourseRosterMaterialsEmail_Query].[Email]) & ";"
  rst.MoveNext
Loop

strEmailAddress = Left(strEmailAddress, Len(strEmailAddress) - 1)

DoCmd.SendObject , , acFormatRTF, strEmailAddress, _
, , [CourseTitle], [Forms]![CourseRosterMaterials_Form]![Details], False, False

rst.Close
Set rst = Nothing

Exit_Command17_Click:
    Exit Sub

Err_Command17_Click:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Exit_Command17_Click

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```vb
Private Sub Command17_Click()
    On Error GoTo Err_Command17_Click

    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
    Dim strEmailAddress

    Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset([CourseRosterMaterialsEmail_Query])

    Do Until rst.EOF
      strEmailAddress = strEmailAddress & rst("Email") & ";"
      rst.MoveNext
    Loop

    strEmailAddress = Left(strEmailAddress, Len(strEmailAddress) - 1)

    DoCmd.SendObject , , acFormatRTF, strEmailAddress, _
    , , [CourseTitle], [Forms]![CourseRosterMaterials_Form]![Details], False, False

    rst.Close
    Set rst = Nothing

    Exit_Command17_Click:
        Exit Sub

    Err_Command17_Click:
        MsgBox Err.Description
        Resume Exit_Command17_Click

End Sub
```

Usually to refer to fields in Recordsets you need to do this:

```vb
rst("FieldName") 'May be ambiguous
rst("FieldAliasName") 'Only if you use aliases
rst("tablename.fieldname") 'I'm actually not sure if this always works
rst("[field name]") 'Use brackets for tables with spaces, symbols, or reserved words
```